# How to keep page links from causing dropdown links to disappear

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

On this page: http://www.theionclub.com/about/contact/

When I mouseover the "About" main nav menu selection, a dropdown appears, as it should.

If I attempt to mouse down to the last selection in the dropdown, though, the hover of the first link underneath, in the left sidebar, appears to cancel the dropdown, making the last link in the dropdown unclickable.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1;` to **.menu li ul{}** section and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add:

.menu li ul { z-index:1;}